# Cant get default method from MemoryCache when set as a class property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, memorycache

I am trying to avoid this:

```
 private ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default
```

By creating a class:

```
public static class MemoryDefault
{
    public static MemoryCache Memory { get; set; }
}
```

When calling MemoryDefault.Memory.Default
it does not exists, why?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "it does not exist"? Where are you using it vs where you're declaring it? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property `public static MemoryCache Memory { get; set; }` is not initialized anywhere - so it will be always `null`..

It should rather be:

```
public static class MemoryDefault
{
    static MemoryDefault()
    {
         Memory = MemoryCache.Default;
    }

    public static MemoryCache Memory { get; private set; }
    //private set for preventing user to change that value
}
```

Other approach:

```
public static class MemoryDefault
{
    public static MemoryCache Memory { get { return MemoryCache.Default; } }
}
```